# Showing the File Extensions inside the folder

Tags: vb.net

Currently, I am working on a feature that will make the files inside the folder that will not hide the file extensions using this code.

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Sub SetNoDrives(value As Integer, path as string)
  Dim RegPath As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]"
    Using Key As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegPath)
        Key.SetValue("HideFileExt", value, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
    End Using
End Sub
```

the problem is, I don't know where to place the string `path (folder path)` on the code. the path is the specific location where you will always show the file extensions of the files inside the folder.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't know where to put the folder path is because there is nowhere to put the folder path. This is a user-wide option, i.e. either extensions are displayed in every folder or no folder for the current user. You don't get to choose on a folder by folder basis. At least, there is no option in Windows/File Explorer to do that and I've never seen mention of it being possible, even when specifically searching for it.

Comment: Thank you sir. But what can I do to always show the file extension using the code above. what should be the value of a `value` to show the file extensions?

Comment: You can easily work that out for yourself. Use the check box in the Folder Options dialogue in Windows/File Explorer and see what values result in Registry Editor. Those are the values you should use in code. You should never be asking a question here that you can answer for yourself.